# substr_count issue or maybe use regular expressions instead

Tags: php, regex

this is what I have right now:

```
$text = "test"; 
$count = substr_count($text, "Hello Everyone this is a 
                                  test test test that im testing");
```

the value $count is 4. I would like to say 3 instead because the word testing is not the same as test.
I am open to doing this using regular expressions if its better/easier ?
any suggestions please

Comment: This code is just plain wrong, the needle is second argument and you left out what's `$text`.

Comment: `substr_count` is not aware of words, it just searches substring occurrences - use a regex to find out.

Comment: @Jack fixed. moonwave: any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the word boundary escape sequence `\b` in `preg_match_all()`:

```
$count = preg_match_all('/\btest\b/', "Hello Everyone this is a 
                              test test test that im testing");
```

See also: [Escape sequences](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php)

Comment: would that return the number of how many times the word test is repeated?

Comment: @fogsy why don't you try and find out? but yes, it returns 3 if that's what you mean :)

Comment: yeah the reason I asked is because I did try it and it didnt return anything ehh

Comment: @fogsy I'm going to go on a limb here and assume you used the wrong value for `$text`; I've changed the answer to be more explicit.

Comment: copy and paste your code and use echo $count return nothing at all. print_r($count) is empty as well ... do you think its a server thing ? (I ve been using php for quiet a while I wouldnt miss $text btw and thanks for going an extra step to make it more explicit)

Comment: @fogsy nothing could be false, var_dump() can confirm that, in which case the pattern didn't compile properly. but afaict the pattern is correct.

Comment: thanks for all the help Jack, no idea why its not echoing the result but I am sure you are correct so I marked this as solved will investigate further.